# ShallowWrapper::setState() can only be called on class components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

this test was passing before i using `withSnackbar`. but now it fails and i really don't know how to fix that. So any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my export in the component:

```js
export default withSnackbar(StoryApp)
```

And here is my test:

```js
let story = {
  Title: "title 1",
  body: "body 1",
  UserEntityKey: "userEntityKey",
  Key: "storyKey"
}

afterEach(() => {
  // cleaning up the mess left behind the previous test
  MockAxios.reset();
});

test('Story deletes based on mocked backend response', async () => {
  window.confirm = jest.fn()
  window.confirm.mockReturnValue(1);

  let idToken = "asdf"

  MockAxios.delete.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
    Promise.resolve(story.Key)
  )

  const storyApp = shallow(<StoryApp />);

  storyApp.setState((prev) => {
    prev.data.push(story)
    return prev
  })

  // Test without idToken
  await storyApp.instance().deleteStory(story)
  expect(MockAxios.delete).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(storyApp.state().data.length).toEqual(1)

  // Test with idToken
  storyApp.setState((prev) => {
    prev.user = { idToken: idToken }
    return prev
  })
  await storyApp.instance().deleteStory(story)
  expect(MockAxios.delete).toHaveBeenCalledWith(apiUrl + '?key=' + story.Key, { headers: { 'Authorization': idToken } });
  expect(storyApp.state().data.length).toEqual(0)
})
```

And here is the output:

● Story deletes based on mocked backend response

```
ShallowWrapper::setState() can only be called on class components

  101 |   const storyApp = shallow(<StoryApp />);
  102 | 
> 103 |   storyApp.setState((prev) => {
      |            ^
  104 |     prev.data.push(story)
  105 |     return prev
  106 |   })

  at ShallowWrapper.setState (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:639:17)
  at Object.setState (__tests__/App.test.js:103:12)
  at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
  at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:288:22)
  at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
  at asyncGeneratorStep (__tests__/App.test.js:25:103)
  at _next (__tests__/App.test.js:27:194)
  at __tests__/App.test.js:27:364
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/App.test.js:27:97)
```

Answer (score 8):

Making original classes like `StoryApp` local harms the testability. Imported `StoryApp` is decorated with `withSnackbar` HOC and isn't class component.

A HOC should either expose original component that will be available, e.g. `WrappedComponent` property.

Or a module should export both decorated and original component:

```
export class StoryApp ...

export default withSnackbar(StoryApp)
```

This way it can be tested like:

```
import StoryApp, { StoryApp as OriginalStoryAppClass } from '...';
...
const wrapper = shallow(<StoryApp />);
const storyApp = wrapper.find(OriginalStoryAppClass).dive();
```

Comment: Thanks @estus but now i get something else:

Method “dive” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.

What do you mean OriginalStoryAppClass? May class name is StoryApp, so i use it instead of  OriginalStoryAppClass.

Comment: Class name doesn't matter. `OriginalStoryAppClass` should be original class component. If you export it like it was suggested, import it like `import { StoryApp: OriginalStoryAppClass }`. I cannot say what may be possible reasons for it not work because you didn't provide the code you're testing.

Answer (score 0):

My class definition looks like below:

```
export class App extends React.PureComponent {}
```

and redux store definition looks like:

```js
const AppStore = withDisclosureManager(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(injectIntl(AppStore)))

export default EditModeQuestionnaireSectionDetailsStore
```

when I do import App in jest with following:

```js
// This doesn't work
import { App } from './App' 

// This works
import App from './App'
```

Comment: Is there any alternative for setState for modifying state variables in functional components?